# Active WCF STS from scratch to end

Tags: wcf, single-sign-on, token, wif

I 've a problem with using WIF to secure WCF services. I just can't make it work.
I've read so many things about it in so many places, but that are not official documentation nor complete, that i start getting confused and don't know where to look for real info...

The thing i want to achieve is having a SSO strategy for several asp.Net applications and WCF services.
I understand that i have to use passive STS for Webapp and active STS for WCF client, but i can't make it work.

The scenario i'd like to have working is this :

Having a common STS for apps and WCF and then

1. Login on webapp1
2. Going to app2 and being already loged in (until here it's OK)
3. call a webservice from app1 hosted on webapp2 without signing again (from here i have trouble)
4. call a webservice from a client (WPF for instance), by loging to the STS.

So does anyone know or have a sample, doc or demo that shows how to do this from scratch ? Cause all the identitylabs and so on are all pre-configured, and/ or not well-documented.

Thanx for reading, hope to have some answers here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Federate-Windows-Live-ID-556ad976

Only one things not solve in this: it does not works correctly on named website.
It is fully working on localhost and on ip(127.0.0.x or 192.168.1.x)

Comment: YOU'RE MY HERO ! Thank you so much ! :)))))))